# Способы определения дорожных знаков на изображении

Tags: python, изображения, opencv

Начал изучать OpenCV для написания программы определения дорожных знаков на языке Python
Способ следующий : используются findcontours и drawcontours, на изображении рисуются контура, появляется подпись о форме (круг, квадрат, ромб и тд).
Читал, что можно определять знаки и тд путем сравнения с эталонным изображением. Не очень понятно какие функции необходимо использовать для данного метода, есть ли те, кто сможет объяснить?

Comment: Искомая вами функция - это `cv2.matchTemplate`, но это ужасная реализация вашей задачи. Вам необходима CNN (convolution neural network) - сверточная нейронная сеть. CNN выделяет признаки на изображении, от чего можно сделать вывод: присутствует ли объект на изображении. Те еще дебри, но это будет единственно верным решением.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ, подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли какие-то примеры программ с cv2.matchTemplate?
Можете ли вы посоветовать, где лучше и подробнее узнать о реализации программы с помощью CNN?